# Get all numbers 1-100 per ID even without data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

| ID | money_earned | days_since_start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 |
| 1 | 3000 | 4 |
| 1 | 2000 | 5 |
| 2 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 3 |

I want that rows, without a days_since_start (which means that the money_earned column was empty that day) - will include all the days PER ID, with "money" being null to indicate there was no earnings, so it to look like this:

| ID | money_earned | days_since_start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 |
| 1 | NULL | **3** |
| 1 | 3000 | 4 |
| 1 | 2000 | 5 |
| 2 | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | NULL | **2** |
| 2 | 100 | 3 |

I have tried to look up for something like that, but I don't even know what function does that...

thank you!

Comment: You need to outer join to a digits/tally table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first generate table for your ids and days by query

```
SELECT d1.id, generate_series(1, max(d1.days_since_start)) AS days_since_start
FROM days d1 JOIN days d2 ON d1.id = d2.id GROUP BY d1.id
```

(if you need all numbers from *1* to *100*, you can replase exspression  *max(d1.days_since_start)* with the number *100*)

and then join it with your table. the final query might look like this

```
WITH genDays AS
     (SELECT d1.id, generate_series(1, max(d1.days_since_start)) AS days_since_start
      FROM days d1 JOIN days d2 ON d1.id = d2.id GROUP BY d1.id)

SELECT coalesce(genDays.id, d3.id) AS id,
       d3.money_earned,
       coalesce(d3.days_since_start, genDays.days_since_start) AS days_since_start
FROM days d3 FULL JOIN genDays ON genDays.id = d3.id
                     AND genDays.days_since_start = d3.days_since_start
```

the output will be as you need

if you need to fill the nulls with last nonnull value per id then you can modify the query like here

```
WITH genDays AS
     (SELECT d1.id as id, generate_series(1,  100) AS days_since_start
      FROM days d1 JOIN days d2 ON d1.id = d2.id GROUP BY d1.id)

SELECT coalesce(genDays.id, d3.id) AS id,
       coalesce(d3.money_earned, 
            (
                select d4.money_earned
                from days d4
                where d4.id = genDays.id
                  and d4.days_since_start < genDays.days_since_start
                order by d4.days_since_start desc
                limit 1
            )) as money_earned,
       coalesce(d3.days_since_start, genDays.days_since_start) AS days_since_start
FROM days d3 FULL JOIN genDays ON genDays.id = d3.id
                  AND genDays.days_since_start = d3.days_since_start
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I want now to fill the nulls with last nonnull value *PerID*, how do I do that?

Comment: @NightHawk I edited my answer to answer your question

Comment: that only works if there aren't multiple nulls in a row

Comment: @NightHawk right, improved it

Comment: there is a problem at your "select d4.money_earned
                from days d4
                where d4.id = genDays.id
                  and d4.days_since_start < genDays.days_since_start
                order by d4.days_since_start desc
                limit 1
            )) as money_earned"
there is no join with genDays, so it doesn't have access to it

Comment: Never-mind, i've put the genDays that's outside, and it works!
you don't know how many hours i've put to this, THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU
This is the most simple solution i've seen to this kind of problem!